# copy an $sce created object and modify its value

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a variable which is like this:-

```
tableData1[$scope.tableHeadingsConstant[0]] = $sce.trustAsHtml('<div class="header12" id="runTitle0" style="cursor: pointer;">'
                     + counter++ + '</div>')
```

now i want to copy it, unwrap it, change the value of div and then wrap it again.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$sce.getTrustedHtml` to obtain the original value.

For example:

```
$scope.value1 = $sce.trustAsHtml('<div>1</div>');

var unwrapped = $sce.getTrustedHtml($scope.value1);

unwrapped = unwrapped.replace('1', '2');

$scope.value2 = $sce.trustAsHtml(unwrapped);
```